# Sum of little $o$

Tags: real-analysis, limits, asymptotics

If I have to consider the Taylor's expansion in solving a limit.

If I have $n\to\infty$ then if for instance I have $$\frac{1}{n+1}+ o(1/(n+1))+\frac{1}{n+2}+o(1/(n+2))+\frac{1}{n}+o(1/n)$$
What's about the sum of the three little $o$? Saying $o(1/n)$ is as saying $o(1/(n+1))$ and so the sum is simply $o(1/n)$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. As $n \to \infty$,
$$
\frac{1}{n+1} \sim \frac{1}{n+2} \sim \frac{1}{n}
$$
so
$$
o\left(\frac{1}{n+1}\right) + o\left(\frac{1}{n+2}\right) + o\left(\frac{1}{n}\right) = o\left(\frac{1}{n}\right) .
$$

---

This only works for finite sums!  You cannot say
$$ 
\frac{1}{n^2}= o\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)
$$
therefore
$$
\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^2} = o\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)
$$
Even worse, you cannot say
$$
\frac{1}{n} \to 0
$$
and so
$$
\frac{1}{n} + \dots + \frac{1}{n}
$$
with $n$ terms yields
$$
\frac{1}{n} + \dots + \frac{1}{n} \to 0
$$

Comment: Ok thanks! Another thing: $1/n^3+1/n^2+o(1/n^2)=1/n^3+o(1/n^2)$? I mean can I collect $1/n^2$ in $o(1/n^2)$?

Comment: No.  $1/n^2 = O(1/n^2)$, but not $o(1/n^2)$.

Comment: Ok so neither as asymptotic equality holds right? Otherwise $1/n^3+1/n^2+o(1/n^2)\sim 1/n^2+o(1/n^2)$?